# Creating a List With Associative Arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to create a **list with a couple of associative arrays**, for script simplicity and creation of new future arrays.

The thing is, where in `python` I would just create a `list({}, {})`, in `bash` I currently can't even create a list pointing to the dictionary.

```
programs=(foo bar)

for program in "${programs[@]}"; do # Declare all arrays in programs
    declare -A $program
done

foo[var]=`ls -al ~` # Declare some variables in each array
bar[var]=`ls -al /`

for program in "${programs[@]}"; do # Print each var key in each array
    if [ "${${program}[var]+True}" = True ]; then
        echo ${${program}[var]}
    fi
done
```

And it just keeps giving me an `bad substitution` error. I'm aware that nested arrays is impossible in `bash`, but is pointing to an array also impossible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use indirect parameter expansion.

```
for program in "${program[@]}"; do
  t=$program[var]   # This is a literal string, not an array expansion
  echo "${!t}"      # This is an indirect array expansion
done
```

Comment: This is it, thanks ! I just happen to be with another problem related to this. `if [ "${${!t}+True}" = True ]` it's for checking if the key exists, but throws the same error.

Comment: You can't nest parameter expansions; that's why the indirect expansion is necessary in the first place. The shell isn't really suited for building data structures.

Comment: Or if you're can take the heat for using a currently unsupported software, look at ksh93 with compound variables and the sub-variables, i.e. `echo ${.sh} -> 
command dollar edchar edcol edmode edtext file fun global level lineno match name namespace stats subscript subshell type value version` and `echo ${.sh.version} -> Version JM 93t+ 2010-05-24` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, thanks for the help, but I would rather not, since it's for use in production environments.

Comment: @Flippym : Yeah, I understand. Actually, I may be overspeaking about unsupported. If  your OS vendor has it it installed (as Oracle VMs do (for example)), then maybe it qualifes as supported. YRMV. I failed to mention that you can go arbitrarily deep with those assignments, i.e. `var.sub1.sub2.sub3.sub4...=value`.and you can use them much as the C lang `struct`s work as well as "type" the subelements. Good luck.