# Indirect reference to array values in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, reference

I am trying to do an indirect reference to values in an array in bash.

```
anotherArray=("foo" "faa")

foo=("bar" "baz")
faa=("test1" "test2")


for indirect in ${anotherArray[@]}
do

echo ${!indirect[0]}
echo ${!indirect[1]}

done
```

This does not work. I tried a lot of differenct things to get the different values of $foo by echoing $indirect but I can only get the first value, all values, '0' or nothing at all.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/40306171/3266847

Answer (score 4):

You have to write the index in the variable used for indirection :

```
anotherArray=("foo" "faa")
foo=("bar" "baz")
faa=("test1" "test2")

for indirect in ${anotherArray[@]}; do
  all_elems_indirection="${indirect}[@]"
  second_elem_indirection="${indirect}[1]"
  echo ${!all_elems_indirection}
  echo ${!second_elem_indirection}
done
```

If you want to iterate over every element of every arrays referenced in `anotherArray`, do the following :

```
anotherArray=("foo" "faa")
foo=("bar" "baz")
faa=("test1" "test2")

for arrayName in ${anotherArray[@]}; do
  all_elems_indirection="${arrayName}[@]"
  for element in ${!all_elems_indirection}; do
    echo $element;
  done
done
```

Alternatively you could directly store the whole indirections in your first array : `anotherArray=("foo[@]" "faa[@]")`

Comment: Okay, I thought there might be a more elegant way to do this instead of assigning every single value of the array to a separate variable to use it in the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Modern versions of bash adopt a ksh feature, "namevars", that's a perfect fit for this issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[012]) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

anotherArray=("foo" "faa")

foo=("bar" "baz")
faa=("test1" "test2")

for indirectName in "${anotherArray[@]}"; do
  declare -n indirect="$indirectName"
  echo "${indirect[0]}"
  echo "${indirect[1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need do it in two steps

```
$ for i in ${anotherArray[@]}; do 
     t1=$i[0]; t2=$i[1]; 
     echo ${!t1} ${!t2};  
  done

bar baz
test1 test2
```

Comment: It's not exactly two steps, he could set `anotherArray=("foo[@]" "faa[1]")` and the indirections would access the specific elements rather than just the first.

Comment: Yes, there can be infinitely many more variations but that's not what the OP is asking for.