# array manipulation using indirection

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'd like to use arrays in BASH properly when using indirection `${!varname}`.

Here's my sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i="1 2 3"
x=CONFIG
y1=( "A and B" "B and C" )
# y1=( "\"A and B\"" "\"B and C\"" )
y2=( "ABC and D" )
y3=

echo "y1=${y1[@]}"
echo "y2=${y2[@]}"
echo "y3=${y3[@]}"
echo "==="

for z in $i
do
    t=y${z}
    tval=( ${!t} )
    r=0
    echo "There are ${#tval[@]} elements in ${t}."
    if [ ${#tval[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        r=1
        echo "config_y${z}=\""
    fi
    for tv in "${tval[@]}"
    do
        [ -n "${tv}" ] && echo "${tv}"
    done
    if [ "x$r" == "x1" ]; then
        echo "\""
    fi
done
```

Here's the result:

```
y1=A and B B and C
y2=ABC and D
y3=
===
There are 3 elements in y1.
config_y1="
A
and
B
"
There are 3 elements in y2.
config_y2="
ABC
and
D
"
There are 0 elements in y3.
```

What I would like to get instead is:

```
y1=A and B B and C
y2=ABC and D
y3=
===
There are 2 elements in y1.
config_y1="
A and B
B and C
"
There are 1 elements in y2.
config_y2="
ABC and D
"
There are 0 elements in y3.
```

I also tried to run something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i="1 2 3"
x=CONFIG
y1=( "A and B" "B and C" )
# y1=( "\"A and B\"" "\"B and C\"" )
y2=( "ABC and D" )
y3=
for variable in ${!y@}
do
  echo "$variable"        # This is the content of $variable
  echo "${variable[@]}"   # So is this
  echo "${!variable}"     # This shows first element of the indexed array
  echo "${!variable[@]}"  # Not what I wanted
  echo "${!variable[0]} ${!variable[1]}"  # Not what I wanted
  echo "---"
done
```

Ideally, `${!Variable[@]}` should do what I want, but it doesn't.
Also, `${!Variable}` only shows the first element of the array,

What can I try?

Comment: This might also be of assistance to you: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for accessing arrays is wrong here:

```
tval=( ${!t} )
```

This will evaluate to e.g. `$y1` but you want `"${y1[@]}"` which is how you address an array with that name with proper quoting.

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to refer to an array through indirection, but see [Indirect reference to array values in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307250/indirect-reference-to-array-values-in-bash) for a couple of workarounds.

Notice also how

```
y3=()
```

is different from

```
y3=
```

Using variables for stuff which isn't actually variable is a bit of a code smell, too.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i="1 2 3"
x=CONFIG
y1=( "A and B" "B and C" )
y2=( "ABC and D" )
# Fix y3 assignment
y3=()

echo "y1=${y1[@]}"
echo "y2=${y2[@]}"
echo "y3=${y3[@]}"
echo "==="

for z in $i
do
    # Add [@] as in Aaron's answer to the linked question
    t=y${z}[@]
    # And (always!) quote the variable interpolation
    tval=( "${!t}" )
    r=0
    echo "There are ${#tval[@]} elements in ${t}."
    if [ ${#tval[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        r=1
        echo "config_y${z}=\""
    fi
    for tv in "${tval[@]}"
    do
        [ -n "${tv}" ] && echo "${tv}"
    done
    if [ "x$r" = "x1" ]; then
        echo "\""
    fi
done
```

Probably also investigate `printf` for unambiguously printing values.

Comment: As you can see, code in comments doesn't really work. You can use another gratuitous variable if you like, of course, but I would advise against using upper case for your private variables.